# Printing words into a file from Bayesian

Tags: python, file

I am using the following library in `Python` called `Bayesian` -> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bayesian. I want to `print` the words that are spam and not spam in `separate files`, because I was following the example of the spam filter and I wanted to adapt it to  use files.

However, my method to write in file isn't working in this case, even if I want to write the entire text of the e-mail:

```
def stxtH(l): #it is the method to write in file:
    with open("HAM.txt", "a") as f:
        words = l.split()
        for word in words:
            f.write(word + " ")
```

The program prints a line (in this case `l`) and it says if the line is a spam mail or not. But I want the program to write in a file the words by if each word is spam or not:

```
b.update_from_events(l.split(), wordsInt) 
#wordsInt is a dictionary with tuples
print l + " ...", b.most_likely()
if b.most_likely() == "ham":
    stxtH(l)
else:
    stxtS(l)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is the file being created and nothing being put into it? Is `l` defined how you'd expect?

Comment: The files are already created. `l` is defined. I only have problem to write the words of the results into two separated files by if the result is spam or not

Comment: So your code is entering the right function, it's just an issue with the for loop/write line in that the file is not being populated? Or are you not entering the right function for spam/not spam emails? I'm still not quite sure what exactly you're having issues with.

Comment: I have problems with the method to write in a file, it does not populate the file. The function to detect spam/ham mails is right.

Comment: If you were to delete "HAM.txt", and rerun the code, does the file get made? When you're writing each word to the file, what happens when you print it out (do you see anything printed)?

Comment: If I delete those files, then the method creates the new archives. I didn't tried to delete the archives, thank you so much for your idea.